# sort a list that contains dictionaries with same key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, sorting

I have four dictionaries that have same key and different value.
I want to print them after sorted by the values, but I can not sort them.

I want to sort dictionaries with the value of first key, if they are equal, sort with another key and its value.

Comment: Please checkout [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`sorted`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted) [which returns a new list] or [`.sort`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort) [which just sorts whichever list it's applied to in-place and does not return anything] with a [`lambda`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function)-expression as the [`key`](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-key-sort-sorted-max-min/) parameter. If you had a list of dictionaries `dictList` and a list of keys `keysList`, you could use

```py
sortedList = sorted(dictList, key=lambda d: [d.get(k) for k in keysList])
```

or

```py
dictList.sort(key=lambda d: [d.get(k) for k in keysList])
```

---

For example, if you had <kbd>`keysList = ['key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3']`</kbd> and

```
dictList = [
 {'key_1': 8, 'key_2': 6, 'key_3': 3, 'key_4': 7}, 
 {'key_1': 4, 'key_2': 2, 'key_3': 4, 'key_4': 4},
 {'key_1': 4, 'key_2': 5, 'key_3': 3, 'key_4': 3},
 {'key_1': 8, 'key_2': 5, 'key_3': 9, 'key_4': 2},
 {'key_1': 4, 'key_2': 5, 'key_3': 9, 'key_4': 0},
 {'key_1': 0, 'key_2': 7, 'key_3': 1, 'key_4': 0},
 {'key_1': 9, 'key_2': 0, 'key_3': 5, 'key_4': 5}]
```

then after being sorted by `key_1` first, then `key_2` and then `key_3`, the list would look like

> [image: op]

Answer (score 0):

Put the dictionaries in a list.  [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) can be used to fetch the primary and secondary keys for sorting:

```py
import operator
from pprint import pprint

data = [{'key1': 5, 'key2': 3},
        {'key1': 3, 'key2': 7},
        {'key1': 4, 'key2': 2},
        {'key1': 4, 'key2': 1},
        {'key1': 2, 'key2': 8}]

data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('key1', 'key2'))
pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
[{'key1': 2, 'key2': 8},
 {'key1': 3, 'key2': 7},
 {'key1': 4, 'key2': 1},
 {'key1': 4, 'key2': 2},
 {'key1': 5, 'key2': 3}]
```